# Custom Segue VS Custom Transition

Tags: ios7, storyboard, custom-transition

Today I tried to perform a custom segue for `UINavigationController` push/pop operations and I didn't find a solution.

I can obviously perform the push operation with a custom segue with no problem, but the pop operation (using the default back button) seems to be complicated (Some notes here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html).

On the other side with iOS 7 performing custom transitions is quite simple and I can achieve a custom push/pop operations thanks to new APIs.

I which case you choose to create custom transitions and when you just work with custom segue?

My question is probably quite generic and it depends on what we need to do... But I'd like to have your opinion.

Comment: I have exactly the same question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform a pop navigation with segues, A segues is only forward or one Directional, it can go reverse from its tack trace, you would have to manually pop your controllers using a back button, also I would go for Segues if I have a simple navigational app like the one's where you go from one controller to next , but choose Custom Transitions, when the navigation depends upon the data values or you need to perform a different action at a different input